# PHP / Статические методы или экземпляры класса?

Tags: php, ооп

Что лучше использовать для (не слишком нагруженного) соединения с базой данных - класс со статическими методами (в этом случае каждый раз при вызове метода придется подключаться к базе данных, производить запрос и отключаться) или же обычный класс с методами (в этом случае нужно будет создавать экземпляр класса на каждой странице и обращаться уже к нему)?

Comment: Не думаю, что тут можно дать объективно хороший ответ. Помимо статики или синглтона можно использовать также DI, service repository и еще много чего. Правильно задаться вопросом: какое время жизни должно быть у соединения, кто ответственен за его инициализацию и деинициализацию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то среднее - использовать [паттерн Singleton](http://www.andrey-vasiliev.com/php/prakticheskaya-realizaciya-patterna-singleton-na-php/).

Comment: Благодарю, как-то упустил из внимания это очевидное решение. А вот ещё небольшой вопрос, можно ли (чисто теоретически) хранить переменную с подключением в глобальных массивах, например, в сессии?

Comment: В сессии - нет, а глобально - вполне. Но глобальные переменные - зло, почему, думаю, знакомо.

Comment: Синглтон по сути и есть глобальная переменная, поэтому с ними надо осторожно

Comment: С такой логикой всё, что может быть запущено, создано или доступно, является глобальной переменной.

Comment: Если баз несколько, что бывает повсеместно - синглтон не прокатит, поэтому минус.

Answer (score 1):

1. Подключаться и отключаться поле ыполнения каждого запроса - это гарантированно убить базу.
2. Статические методы можно использовать и без такого варварства - поскольку кроме статических методов есть еще и статические свойства, которые вполне могут хранить соединение с БД.
3. Статику не очень любят тестировщики, поэтому если хочется прямо по фен-шую и заветам атцоф-основателей, то делаешь один класс.
4. А уж за слово "синглетон" тебя на больном стаковерфлоу в землю в топчут, потом порвут на куски и [провернут через мясорубку](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons).

Comment: Спасибо. Подключаться каждый раз действительно невыгодно, изначально у меня был класс со статическими методами, но к синглтону я почему-то не пришёл, попробую.
Кстати, а за что на стаковерфлоу так не любят это слово?

Answer (score 1):

Статический класс или синглтон разницы для базы особо нет. Да и вообще разницы принципиальной нет, что именно у вас будет объектом - класс как объект или настоящий экземпляр как объект, это уже как религия позволяет.

Для БД главное не закрывать соединение, никуда кешировать и сохранять его не нужно, php-расширения такие как mysqli, pdo (но не mysql) сделают это за вас.